# Swift - Filter json response based on if it contains a certain key

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary, swift3

I am wondering if I can filter a response from an API request based on if an item in the array contains a certain key.

I want to filter the array so that I only have instances of dictionaries that contain `["section": "name", "balls": 0, "bananas": 0]` and have `["section_group": "group", "balls": 0, "bananas": 0]` instances removed.

How would I do that in Swift?

I guess I should do something to `data` before I decode it here

```
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                recipes = response.results
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Structs:

```
struct Response: Decodable, Encodable {
    let results: [Data]
}

struct Data: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let name: String
    let thumbnail_url: String
    let sections: [Section]
    let instructions: [Instruction]
    let num_servings: Int
    let prep_time_minutes: Int?
    let cook_time_minutes: Int?
    let total_time_minutes: Int?
}

struct Section: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let components: [Ingredient]
}

struct Ingredient: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let raw_text: String
}

struct Instruction: Decodable, Hashable, Encodable {
    let display_text: String
}
```

Comment: What format is the response? Array of JSON objects?

Comment: Here you can see the example response: https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/tasty/ (GET recipes/list endpoint then click on example responses on the right)

Comment: That website is not loading for me. Is this an array of dictionaries `[[String: Any]]` or an array of structs? or something else?

Comment: ill upload some pictures. It is an array of dictionaries

Comment: Im basically trying to only get items from results that contain 50 items and remove ones that have 28 items. I know that the ones that contain 50 items have a "sections" key where the ones with 28 items do not.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter an array of dictionaries as follows:

```swift
let desired_results = all.filter{$0.keys.contains("sections")}
```

where `all` is your array of `[String: Any]` dictionaries.

The closure returns a boolean, true if the keys of the dictionary contain "sections".

More about filter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter

edit: If you want to filter `Response.results` to only include the 50-key objects, you can ignore ones that fail to be decoded as follows:

```swift
struct Response: Decodable, Encodable {
    let results: [String]
}
```

I renamed your `Data` to `Recipe` because Data is already a type, and you should use a different name.

```swift
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)

recipes = response.results.compactMap({
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipe.self, from: Data($0))
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
})
```

compactMap ignores the nil values, which are the ones where JSONDecoder fails to decode (the objects). This way you have an array of `Recipe`

Comment: Thank you that will work. But for some reason the data I am getting back from the API request says that it does not contain `keys`

Comment: I updated with new code. I realize I should do something with data before I decode the json. I just don't know how to filter the data object...

Comment: @StasysMeclazcke That's right. From the screenshot you sent, the actual array of dictionaries is embedded inside an outer object, in the key "results"

Comment: do you know how I can do that? I appreciate your help so much! I've tried every way I can think of filtering the data before I decode it, but I haven't found a way to exclude the ones missing a key

Comment: @StasysMeclazcke use the code in the answer after `recipes = response.results`. `all` would be `recipes` in this case.

Comment: when I do that it says that `Recipes` has no member keys

Comment: Please add all your struct definitions to the question.

Comment: Thank you @atultw I updated with structs

Comment: I would suggest reading about basic swift data structures before taking on such a task. You say you want to filter an array of dictionaries, but you have only structs. Additionally I don't see any mention of balls and bananas. Structs don't have keys, as the error suggests. If you have an array of structs, they are all guaranteed to have the same *fields*. So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: I need to filter the json data before I decode it with the structs. Because the API I am using (Tasty API) returns two different types of data with a query. I have a struct that can decode one type of data, but the other one has different keys.

Comment: Oh ok, so do I understand correctly that you want to filter the data *before* decoding into structs? That means there are no dictionaries involved. I will update the answer with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242867/discussion-between-atultw-and-stasys-meclazcke).